# HERE api Auto suggest not return place position anymore

Tags: here-api

in my app(on launch) is getting place's position from result of auto suggestion everything is fine but my app is getting error that in place suggestion attribute doesn't contain 'position' field, now my app cannot continue because this error what can i do.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/dev_guide/topics_api/media-type-autosuggest.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP's issue with the `position` field missing from responses to the Places API was resolved by HERE.com. There was some active discussion [in their slack](https://heredev.slack.com) (which is worth joining as it seems the best way to get support :) )

Answer (score 0):

Now if you're urgent. You have to use discover service instead, I'm facing TOO , TT

Comment: Can you explain _how_ the Discover Service resolves this issue?

Comment: i cannot wait so this is my temporary way to resolve this issue , by get place-id then get place location by using lookup. https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoint-lookup-brief.html

Comment: I'm using js sdk  [link](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.17.0/api_reference/H.service.SearchService.html). So if you use rest you can use discover too. In API ref you will see autosuggest and discover

Answer (score 0):

We have the same issue since yesterday: [Here suggest API returns PARSING_ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62690643/here-suggest-api-returns-parsing-error)

We are automatically swapping to google maps api when here doesnt respond.

Comment: yeah , i got this issue yesterday too , i think google map api has high transaction cost , so i resolve this by using HERE lookup instead. https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoint-lookup-brief.html

Comment: but hopefully they will fix this issue soon.

Comment: We use here, but when it fails we automatically switch to google, without user noticing it. Yeah, google costs are outrageously high

Comment: Okay,I got it, i'll apply it in my app later, thx for suggestion.

Comment: This issue should have been fixed already, it's no longer happening for me.