# Here suggest API returns PARSING_ERROR

Tags: routes, here-api, search-suggestion

Since yesterday, our Here API to get place suggestions systematically returns 'PARSING_ERROR'.

The status page at here https://status.here.com/status says all is fine, so what can be the problem?

Our code, operational in live since weeks:

```
if (fromCoordinates == null)
        {
            double lat = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("lat", 0.0);
            double lng = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("long", 0.0);
            fromCoordinates = new GeoCoordinates(lat, lng);
            int maxItems = 5;
            searchOptionsFrom = new SearchOptions(LanguageCode.EN_GB, maxItems);
        }
searchEngine.suggest(
                new TextQuery(input,
                        fromCoordinates),
                searchOptionsFrom,
                autosuggestCallbackFrom);
```

Coordinates are fine and search term is 'London'. We tried with different API keys and different input, but result is always the same. Geocoding and calculateRoute from here work fine.

This is what the callback shows:

[image]

Comment: I have reached out to the SDK team and we're investigating.

Comment: I am having the same situation here

Comment: If you could let me know the exact version of the SDK you are using, that would be hepful.

Comment: It looks like a temporary backend issue that should be fixed soon. HERE team is working on it.

Comment: heresdk-lite-android-4.3.3.0.2052

Comment: resolved the issue?

Comment: no, still not working

Comment: Just to update you, we are aware of the issue and are working on a fix.

Comment: Update: a rollback is currently in progress and things should be back to normal soon.